# SQL: Getting Duplicate Data When Attempting to Sum and Join 2 Tables

Tags: sql

In Essence, I have two tables (purchases and sales) that I need to join together.  Both tables have different Primary Keys, but they share the same foreign key.  Every time a purchase is made, a new entry is made (with it's own primary key).  Every time a sale is made, a new entry is made (with its own key).

Summary of  Used Tables:

```
Purchase Data
  Individual Product Cost (AS IPC)
  Sales Tax (AS ST)
  Quantity (AS Q)
  SKU (Foreign Key)
  Primary Key (AS PK)

Sales
   Amount Sold (AS AS)
   Total (AS T)
   SSKU(Foreign Key)
   Primary Key (AS PK)
```

When I attempt to Sum and Join the data based on the product I get weird results.

Purchase Table Data:

```
    SKU |  IPC  |  ST  | Q | PK 
     1    2.40    .02    5    1
     2    5.00    .05    20   2
     3    4.00    .04    5    3
     1    5.00    .04    20   4
```

Sales Table:

```
    SSKU |  T  |  AS  | PK 
     1     10      2    1
     2     9       1    2
     3     9       4    3
     1     9       1    4
     2     9       2    5
     1     9       2    6
     1     9       4    7
```

Expected Results

```
    SKU  | (IPC + ST)Q   |  Q  |  SUM AS  |  SUM T
     1         354.9        25       9        37 
     2          101         20       3        9
     3          80.8         5       4        18
```

When trying the script creator in OpenOffice Base, It would give me the expected results for product 3, but it would be wrong for products 1 and 2.

I read up on SQL programming, and attempted my hand at it. I THINK this would solve the issue by summing the two tables separately before merging.  Instead, I keep receiving an error now, and I can't find the mistake.

Current Code:

```
SELECT

"A"."SKU"
,SUM(( "A"."Individual Product Cost" + "A"."Sales Tax" ) * "A"."Quantity")
,"A"."Quantity"
,"D"."Sales"
,"D"."Sold"

FROM "PurchaseData" AS "A"

Inner Join

(

Select
"ACT"."SSKU" 
,SUM("ACT"."Amount Sold") AS Sold
,SUM("ACT"."Total") AS Sales

From
"Sales" AS ACT

GROUP BY
"ACT"."SSKU"
)

AS D    

on "A"."SKU" = "D"."SSKU"


Group By
"A"."SKU"
```

EDIT:
According to a random online Syntax checker, it's line 3 (I don't see it).
According to Openoffice Base:

SQL Status: HY000
Error code: 1000

syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting BETWEEN or IN or SQL_TOKEN_LIKE

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: According to a random Syntax checker, its on line 3.  According to OpenOffice Base:
Syntax error in SQL Expression
SQL Status: HY000
Error code: 1000

Syntax error in SQL expression

SQL Status: HY000
Error code: 1000

syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting BETWEEN or IN or SQL_TOKEN_LIKE

Comment: you can sum purchase data in a subquery, the same as you did with sales, and then join both subqueries without aggregation

Comment: I've put it in an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jayvee, I got it working!

```
Select 
"A"."SKU"
,"B"."Sold"
,"B"."Sales"
,"A"."Total Cost"
,"A"."Total Purchased"

From

 -- First Sub Query -- 
(
Select

"PD"."SKU" As SKU
,SUM(( "PD"."Individual Product Cost" + "PD"."Sales Tax" ) *"PD"."Quantity") AS "Total Cost"
,SUM ("PD"."Quantity") AS "Total Purchased"

From
"PurchaseData" AS PD

GROUP BY
"PD"."SKU"
)
As A 

--End First--

Join 
--Start 2nd--
(
Select

"ACT"."SSKU" AS ASKU
,SUM("ACT"."Amount Sold") AS Sold
,SUM("ACT"."Total") AS Sales

From
"Sales" As ACT

GROUP BY
"ACT"."SSKU"
)
As B
--End 2nd--

On
"B"."ASKU" = "A"."SKU"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can sum purchase data in a subquery, the same as you did with sales, and then join both subqueries without aggregation:

```
Select 
"A"."SKU"
,"B"."Sold"
,"B"."Sales"
,"A"."Total Cost"
,"A"."Total Purchased"

From

 -- First Sub Query -- 
(
Select

"PD"."SKU" As SKU
,SUM(( "PD"."Individual Product Cost" + "PD"."Sales Tax" ) *"PD"."Quantity") AS "Total Cost"
,SUM ("PD"."Quantity") AS "Total Purchased"

From
"PurchaseData" AS PD

GROUP BY
"PD"."SKU"
)
As A 

--End First--

Join 
--Start 2nd--
(
Select

"ACT"."SSKU" AS ASKU
,SUM("ACT"."Amount Sold") AS Sold
,SUM("ACT"."Total") AS Sales

From
"Sales" As ACT

GROUP BY
"ACT"."SSKU"
)
As B
--End 2nd--

On
"B"."ASKU" = "A"."SKU"
```